# Backtrack 5 stops at console screen

Tags: backtrack

How do i run backtrack 5 from a cd when my laptop (Toshiba Qosmio x875) runs it up to a point then stops. It runs it to a black screen where the cursor keeps blinking. Has anyone else found this problem and how do i fix it?

Comment: Is it something like "[root@bt]~" or something similar? Have you tried switching TTYs (Ctrt+Alt+F[1-7])?

Comment: @IvanKay has a good question, is there any text whatsoever?

Comment: ill post a pic.

Comment: @OrvillePatterson Well, do post it when you do.